# How can I get log4j's console appender to write the elapsed-time value in hh:mm:milisec format?

Tags: logging, log4j, format, timestamp

I use log4j (and some wrappers), with the conversion pattern `"%r [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n"`. The leftmost value (`%r`) is miliseconds elapsed since execution began. I want this value printed in mm:ss or mm:ss:milisecs - but I still want it to be the elapsed time, not the current time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own Layout. The simplest is just to extend `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` and overwrite the format method.

com.stackoverflow.MyPattern

```
public class MyPattern extends PatternLayout {
@Override public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
    return "MyOwnString" + super.format(event);
}
```

Then configure it as usual:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout=com.stackoverflow.MyPattern
log4j.appender.A1.layout=com.farmnet365.main.impl.jpa.extensions.TimeElapsedPatternLayout
```

You can extend the layout however you like. Here a complete working example that adds elapsed time using joda: [gist](https://gist.github.com/estani/29c58bf1f9b71f120dde1b056136fa15)

Comment: I'm no longer in the company where this issue was relevant, but I'll assume this works.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to set the layout pattern in this way:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:sss z}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

You can reference [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) for all the pattern you can use.

Comment: But won't just give me the current time rather than the elapsed time?